# gen update rake -bash: gen: command not found

Tags: installation, rvm

I have installed Ruby, Rails, RVM, Git, and Homebrew on my Mac with OS X 10.7.  I have also installed Jewelry box and have the following versions of Ruby installed: (1.9.1, 2.0.0).

I can go to a terminal window and perform a gem list command but when I try gem update rake I get the following error:

```
-bash: gen: command not found
```

I fear in all my installing, uninstalling and installing I have somehow gotten a confused environment due to possibly a conflict between a single user install and a multi-user install and do not know how to figure it out.

A `whereis` of Ruby and Rails show them both being in `usr/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such command `gen` - try `gem`, it is possible you might have an `alias gem=gen` or `function gem(){ gen "$@"; }` which could make that happen